# CSS p and ui tag together in same class

Tags: css

I am doing a website in which I want to improve my website design.

I have a css class which affects the `p` tag, so:

```
.Columns .NewBox p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-size: 1.1em; color:Black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also want the same CSS to be set for the `ul` tag.

So I could of course duplicate the same class and just replace the `p` with `ui`, however, I like to keep in the OO conduct and not copy and paste the same code, so I have tried,

```
.Columns .NewBox p + ul {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-size: 1.1em; color:Black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And

```
.Columns .NewBox p ul {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-size: 1.1em; color:Black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Probably a brain freeze...how can it be done?

Comment: Are you looking for `.Columns .NewBox p, .Columns .NewBox ul {...}`? You need to use `,` for multiple selectors, i.e. `p, ul {color:red;}` that will set both tags to red color.

Comment: Jesus, I thought I tired that. I knew it would be simple, but really? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To apply the same styling to different elements, use comma like this:

```css
.Columns .NewBox p,
.Columns .NewBox ul {
    /*  your style code */
}
```

Here is demo for this code: http://jsfiddle.net/rork/8pm8fbss/

Now, I saw your own answer, but please mind that your code would target only child `<p>` elements of elements with classes `.Columns` and `.NewBox` and it would be applied to **ALL** `<ul>`elements on your page, because you haven't narrow selection using css selectors.

```css
.Columns .NewBox p, ul { /*  your style code */ }
```

Here is demo for your code: http://jsfiddle.net/rork/svkv9az3/

In your answer you're targeting `.Columns .NewBox p` and all `ul` elements. Be sure to check if this is something you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that @Nadi , specifying the full path for the targeted `ul` it's essential, unless you want to add that style for all the `ul` tags. But even better would be to create a specific class for the `ul` tag like the following: `<ul class="myulclass"></ul>` and the CSS `.Columns .NewBox p, .myulclass { ... }` . Specifying classes like this can improve the CSS matching time and it's also a better way of structuring things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sdcr for helping me solve my problem. You can style multiple classes and tags just by using a comma like on the example below:

```
.Columns .NewBox p, ul {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-size: 1.1em; color:Black;
    text-align: center;
}
```